# Java 8 Stream to convert Object inside Object of Set to Map

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have an object which has `Set`. Each `Set` of object has another object where that also has `Set` of object.

```
class GroupVO {
    int id;
    Set<MasterVO> master; // This should be changed as Map<masterId, MasterVO>

    //getter, setter
}

class MasterVO {
    int masterId;
    Set<SlaveVO> slave; // This should be changed as Map<slaveId, SlaveVO>

    //getter, setter
}

class SlaveVO {
    int slaveId;
    String title;
    String description;

    //getter, setter
}
```

And I want to convert these `Set` to `Map`.

I'm able to convert it for the first map level. But, I don't know how to get the second 'Set' to `Map` conversion.

```
GroupVO groupVO = new GroupVO();
Map<Integer, MasterVO> masterMap = groupVO.getMaster().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(MasterVO::getMasterId, Function.identity()));
```

Instead of `Function.identity()`, I need to access the `mastervo` object and in that Object I have to convert all the `Set<Slave>`  to `SlaveMap`

Please suggest.

I need it like,
`Map<Integre, MasterVO>`. If I get the `MasterVO` object like `masterMap.get(101)`, then it should have the `SlaveMap` inside.

Comment: Why can't you do the same as you did for MasterVo here?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want a `Map<Integer,Map<Integer,SlaveVO>>`, where the key of the outer `Map` is a master ID and the key of the inner `Map` is a slave ID.

I suggest to create that `Map` by using `flatMap` to obtain a `Stream` of all the MasterVO,SlaveVO pairs. Then you can group the elements of this `Stream` by master ID and use `Collectors.toMap` to create the inner `Map`s.

```
Map<Integer,Map<Integer,SlaveVO>>
     = groupVO .getMaster()
              .stream()
              .flatMap(m -> m.getSlave()
                             .stream()
                             .map(s -> new SimpleEntry<MasterVO,SlaveVO>(m,s)))
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getKey().getID(),
                                             Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getValue().getID(),
                                                              Map.Entry::getValue)));
```

Comment: Hi. I want `Map<Integre, MasterVO>` only. If I get the `MasterVO` object like `masterMap.get(101)`, then it should have the `SlaveMap` inside.

Comment: @Shakthi But your `MasterVO` class has no `Map<Integer,SlaveVO>` property. Do you intend to change that class?

Comment: Can't we create dynamically in the new Map object which I create is? I don't have Map in the MasterVO also. But, still we are converting `Set` as `Map`. Similarly, why can't we create a `Map` object in the child and can assign it to the `Master`?